# How to mark a XCTest as pending?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, tdd, xctest

I have a subclass of `XCTestCase` and I would like to mark some test as `pending`, in the same way that is possible with RSpec

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this. The most pragmatic solution is to comment out or rename your test:

```
@implementation MyTestCase

- (void)testSomething { /* ... */ }

// Option 1: Comment out the test.
// - (void)testSomething { /* ... */ }

// Option 2: Rename the test such that XCTest does not consider 
// it a valid test method. In order to be "valid", it needs to:
// 
// - Have a return type of `void`
// - Take no parameters
// - Begin with "test"
//
// Here, we rename the test so that it does not begin with "test".
- (void)PENDING_testSomething { /* ... */ }

@end
```

Of course, one of the nice things about RSpec is that it prints out a warning of some kind. You could add these yourself using `#warning`:

```
#pragma Pending!
- (void)PENDING_testSomething { /* ... */ }
```

This displays a warning in Xcode. Keep in mind that `#warning` is only available in Objective-C, not Swift.

Testing frameworks like [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) and [Specta](https://github.com/specta/specta) provide pending examples:

```
pending("tests something") { /* ... */ }
xit("tests something") { /* ... */ }
xdescribe("describes something") { /* ... */ }
xcontext("provides context for something") { /* ... */ }
```

These test frameworks prevent "pending" tests from being run by overriding `-[XCTestCase testInvocations]`. Doing so is a lot of work, but if you wanted to implement "pending tests" yourself, you could look into doing so as well.

Comment: One reason to prefer renaming over commenting out is that the compiler will tell you if the pending test fails to build.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly pending, but if your lead considers pending tests a failing suite (I am the lead for my team, and I do), then a simple `XCTFail()` does the job:

```
#pragma mark - Something Tests

- (void)testSomething_scenario_result {
    XCTFail(@"Pending Test: %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

Then you can easily see what failures are relevant if you need to leave a pending test in for whatever reason (maybe a personal development branch), but the whole suite still fails until you complete it.

For "true" pending, modocache's answer is far more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Although semantically perhaps *slightly* different, [XCTSkip()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/methods_for_skipping_tests) may provide what you're looking for as I use it in this manner. It's part of the core XCTest framework.

> Use XCTSkipIf() or XCTSkipUnless() when you have a Boolean condition
> that you can use to evaluate when to skip tests.
>
> Throw an XCTSkip error when you have other circumstances that result
> in skipped tests.

```
func testUpdatesSealCompletedCount() async throws {
    throw XCTSkip("Pending")
}
```

In spite of what having to `throw` this might imply, your test suite will still pass.

The nice bit about this is that it updates the Test Navigator with an icon that looks the debugger "skip over".

[image: Xcode Test Navigator]